# Flutter: How to show real ads on iPhone simulator to get screenshots for App Store

Tags: ios, flutter, admob, app-store-connect

My app submission to the App Store has been rejected because my app screenshots show test ads. I need to capture screenshots of my app with real banner ads showing for the App Store. However, I don't have physical devices for all the screen sizes!

When I run my app on an iPhone simulator, even with the actual Ad unit ID, I just get ads with 'Test mode' shown on top of each ad.

Has anyone else had the same issue? Or can suggest how to resolve this?

Comment: Well maybe you should follow Apple's employee's instruction, and borrow someone iPhone. Or you could try again and hope they don't notice this anymore :)

Comment: Are you sure that you disable debug ads on release?

Comment: I ended up taking out a month's subscription to Browser Stack and uploading and running the IPA file on the required devices to capture the screenshots. Why is everything Apple require shelling out yet more money!